# About API gateway and mapping function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to add kinesis streams to my api gatway to handle data streams, i've created three data streams in kinesis and currently want to create my first get method.

1. For Integration type selected AWS Service
2. For AWS Region choose us-east-1 as this is where its based
3. For AWS Service select Kinesis
4. For HTTP method select POST For Action Type select User action name

- For Action name type DescribeStream For Execution role is the same
  ARN i created for kinesis

Finally in the intergration response model I set the header parameter to accept content type 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'

```
in the template column i included {
    "StreamName": "$input.params('stream-name')"
}
```

Now what i don't get is why is the error of  Invalid mapping expression specified: 'application/x-amz-json-1.1 which is preventing me from saving my get method, i've seen other people's implementation of the same exact scenario and they've done it to the T of what is above unless theres a new aws json protocol out?